# webdriverio textarea set Text

Tags: javascript, html, webdriver, webdriver-io

HTML:

```
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="import-textarea">Use the "Export board" menu item in a board's menu, then copy the json from the resulting file.</label>
  </p>
  <textarea class="js-import-json" placeholder="Paste your valid JSON data here" autofocus=""/>
  <input class="primary wide" type="submit" value="Import">
</form>
```

I want to set the text inside the textarea, with webdriver.io and tried different selectors:

```
const ta = browser.$('textarea');
ta.setValue('Updated Text');

const val = imp.selectByAttribute('placeholder', 'Paste your valid JSON data here');
const text = browser.getText('.js-import-json=Paste your valid JSON data here');
```

But none of them seemed to work. Either i get no text at all or the selector could not be found on page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `const text = ta.getValue();` ? Or `const text = browser.getValue('.js-import-json');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about setValue here http://webdriver.io/api/action/setValue.html  
And about selectors here http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html

I wrote this code only for current situation and I don't recommend writting this way, but it will work

```
browser.setValue('.js-import-json','Updated Text');
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work... gonna try it again.

Comment: Ok it seems like it's working, but when i do `browser.getText('.js-import-json');` it returns empty string, i have to access the text by `browser.getValue...`, why is that?